# Granting OU-limited read AND write admin privileges to On-Premises Exchange Server 2016

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2016, scope, administrative-privileges

I've successfully created a limited Management role, and assigned a user to it, that allows a junior admin only two things via the ECP web page:

-- Reset passwords in a particular Org Unit

-- Create new users in the same

The write privileges are no problem: you just pick the scope.
However they really shouldn't see the AD data (users, groups) for *any other* OU. But when they log in, the Whole World is listed.

Everything I've read seems to give no flexibility to the Read Scope -- that it must be implicit and include the entire Organization: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335146(v=exchg.150).aspx#ImplicitScopes

I know that's an irrational restriction, and there's a way to do what I want, and that it's going to be much more involved than I would ever want, but that it is possible, so I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

*UPDATE* Looks to be not possible: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/a063a190-89a4-4611-aa8d-772ab5a832f7/exchange-2013-rbac-read-scope?forum=exchangesvradmin&prof=required but this is just very surprising.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and several similar posts, it's now clear that it simply is not possible.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/35e1096a-fa9a-4d98-a56a-84b40f4fa0ab/change-implicitrecipientreadscope-in-rbac?forum=exchange2010